# Select top N records after filtering in each group

Tags: c#, linq

I am an old bee in .NET but very new to Linq! After some basic reading I have decided to check my skill and I failed completely! I don't know where I am making mistake.

I want to select highest 2 order for each person for while Amount % 100 == 0.

Here is my code.

```
var crecords = new[] {
               new { 
                    Name = "XYZ", 
                    Orders = new[] 
                    { 
                        new { OrderId = 1, Amount = 340 }, 
                        new { OrderId = 2, Amount = 100 }, 
                        new { OrderId = 3, Amount = 200 } 
                    } 
               },
               new { 
                    Name = "ABC", 
                    Orders = new[] 
                    { 
                        new { OrderId = 11, Amount = 900 }, 
                        new { OrderId = 12, Amount = 800 }, 
                        new { OrderId = 13, Amount = 700 } 
                    } 
                }
            };


        var result = crecords
                            .OrderBy(record => record.Name)
                            .ForEach
                                (
                                    person => person.Orders
                                    .Where(order => order.Amount % 100 == 0)
                                    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Amount)
                                    .Take(2)
                                );


        foreach (var record in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.Name);
            foreach (var order in record.Orders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-->" + order.Amount.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Can anyone focus and tell me what would be correct query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
var result = crecords.Select(person => 
             new
                {
                    Name = person.Name, 
                    Orders = person.Orders.Where(order => order.Amount%100 == 0)
                                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount)
                                          .Take(2)
                });
```

Using your foreach loop to print the resulting IEnumerable, the output of it is:

```
XYZ
-->200
-->100
ABC
-->900
-->800
```

Comment: Beat me too it, the reason for this error is due to the fact that ForEach() return void because it's actually modifying itself so it does not need to return anything. So your `result` will be null

Comment: To be clear, ForEach could have been used, but it would have looked like this:
`crecords.ToList().ForEach(person => { person.Orders = person.Orders.Where(order => order.Amount%100 == 0)                               .OrderByDescending(t => t.Amount)                              .Take(2).ToArray(); }`                                                         Then the foreach would be        `foreach (var record in crecords)`

Comment: Besides missing a closing `)`, that query gives you a compile time error: "Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Orders' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" ;)

Comment: @LasseChristiansen-sw_lasse That's only because we are using anonymous objects. His original code would have done the same. But if he created real People and Order classes, it would work fine.

Comment: @LasseChristiansen-sw_lasse I posted it as an alternative answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered but if you didn't want to create new objects and simply modify your existing `crecords`, the code would look like this alternatively. But you wouldn't be able to use anonymous structures like shown in your example. Meaning you would have to create People and Order classes

```
 private class People
 {
      public string Name;
      public IEnumerable<Order> Orders;
 }

 private class Order
 {
      public int OrderId;
      public int Amount;
 }

 public void PrintPeople()
 {
      IEnumerable<People> crecords = new[] {
           new People{ 
                Name = "XYZ", 
                Orders = new Order[] 
                { 
                    new Order{ OrderId = 1, Amount = 340 }, 
                    new Order{ OrderId = 2, Amount = 100 }, 
                    new Order{ OrderId = 3, Amount = 200 } 
                } 
           },
           new People{ 
                Name = "ABC", 
                Orders = new Order[] 
                { 
                    new Order{ OrderId = 11, Amount = 900 }, 
                    new Order{ OrderId = 12, Amount = 800 }, 
                    new Order{ OrderId = 13, Amount = 700 } 
                } 
            }
        };
        crecords = crecords.OrderBy(record => record.Name);
        crecords.ToList().ForEach(
                person =>
                {
                    person.Orders = person.Orders
                          .Where(order => order.Amount%100 == 0)
                          .OrderByDescending(t => t.Amount)
                          .Take(2);
                }
            );


        foreach (People record in crecords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.Name);
            foreach (var order in record.Orders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-->" + order.Amount.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```